# Using classes in KV language

Tags: python, kivy

```
MyScreenManager:
    id: myscreenmanager
    transition: FadeTransition()
    ScreenOne:
    ScreenTwo:

<Widget>:
    font_name: 'example.ttf'

<ScreenOne>:
     ...

<ScreenTwo>:
     ...
```

When I use a class in kv language, I wish to know how `ClassName:` different from `<ClassName>:`.

It seems to me that there can only be one `ClassName:` which is called root object, or else it will say

> 'Only one root object is allowed by .kv'

So it seems the `ClassName:` is generally a screen manager as far as I've seen in other kivy examples.

Then How do they act differently? Why can't I just make `<MyScreenManager>:`?

(It doesn't give any error, but it does not work somehow.)

This really confuses me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<class>:` are rules, if kivy encounters a widget with this class it applies the content of the fitting rules. Kivy documentation compares this to css rules if you know some webdevelopment.

`class:` defines a root widget. In kivy widgets form a tree, so each widget has one parent and has many children - besides a single root widget wich has no parent. This tree is important because e.g. it defines in what order widgets are drawn. If you would have two roots in which order should they draw? (and if you just say "well just the one then the second" then you could also just create a single root and add the old roots in that order to the new root). Having only a single root simplifies this massively.

The root is often some kind of layout or container because often you want to have multiple widgets shown in your application, and having a container simplifies this. But you could also have a kivy application with a button as root widget.

You don't have to have a root widget in a kv file. This can make sense e.g. when having multiple kv files for different styles. Also the root widget can also be constructed in the [App.build()](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#kivy.app.App.build) method.

Kv files have two further kind of rules, see the [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#overview). There also the difference between rules and root widget is explained.